# Silly Javascript Help

Tags: javascript

```
var showPop = true;
function exitIt(){ 
     if (showPop){ 
     showPop = false;
     return 'blah blah';
     }
}
```

This is a little exit pop up. If the user chooses to "stay on the page", I need it to redirect to the proper URL. How can I do this?

Comment: you missed a closing brace `}`

Comment: sorry missed in copy paste - have it in the file.. my bad.

Answer (score 3):

Just because you can implement something, doesn't mean that you should. Exit popups are arguably the most annoying thing ever!

Comment: Especially when they ask you whether you *really* want to leave. That's why Chrome lets you stop them from appearing after the second one ;)

Comment: This is not a question of Morals / ethics, it is a question on how to do something.

Comment: True. This is the sort of things browsers need to deal with. I seem to recall that Chrome has a bug that's being worked on that patches this behaviour, but I'm not sure how far it got – there are obviously some useful cases such as leaving whilst editing a text box. I think the consensus was to auto fire popups then, but not to allow JS to bind to leaving a page.

Comment: What sort of site is it? I've only ever seen this on the dodgiest of the dodgiest.

Comment: its not a public area - it's an intranet

Comment: It's true that it's not a question of 'morals' but that is why so much software is so crappy. Developers need to be willing to push back on clients when user experience is compromised.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("a#myleavinglink").click(function() {
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you should leave? Its so sweet thougH!");
        if (answer) {
            return true; 
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

You could also do a very similar thing with jQuery and if the user decides to leave the page, or back up, or type in their own address.

BTW, by returning `true` from a click function in jQuery will allow standard operations, but returning `false` will override the standard functionality and only provide the functionality you have choosen.  Hence, if the user wants to leave, it returns true, else it returns false

```
$("a").live("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if (id == approvedClicks) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

that would prevent any links being clicked to be removed, whether at page load, or added in with JS.

Answer (score 0):

or `document.location = "http://www.example.com/";`

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (confirm('Move to another page?')){ 
    window.location = "http://blah.com/";
  }
```